# Create a nested, generic, ordered list in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, list, generics, django-rest-framework

I need to save lists that can contain many promos, many playlists, or many apix_items. The order of the lists' contents matters, and the JSON I receive has these items nested in the list under 'items'

**apix_item list:**

```
{
  "items": [
    "rhmy5prfennp",
    "lpi6ghwfwshp",
    "scb6kn3hbqzd",
  ],
  "title": "Apix Item List",
}
```

**promo list:**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "image": "some_url",
      "id": "promo_1",
    },
    {
      "image": "some_url",
      "id": "promo_2"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Promo Item List"
}
```

I would like to use a ManyToMany relationship but I don't think that will work because a lists' items need to be generic. So instead I have a very simple list model:

```
class List(TimeStamped):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='New List')
```

and an intermediary ListOrder model with a ForeignKeyField and a GenericForeignKey field:

```
class ListOrder(TimeStamped):

    content_types = {
        'app_label__in': (
            'apix_items',
            'playlists',
            'promos',
        ),
        'model__in': (
            'apix_item',
            'playlist',
            'promo',
        ),
    }

    index = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    target_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=content_types)
    target_object = GenericForeignKey('target_type', 'target_id')
    target_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    container = models.ForeignKey(List)
```

I have a feeling I will need to do something crazy in my serializers in order to get this to work:

```
class ListOrderSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ListOrder
        fields = (
            'index',
            'target_object',
            'created', 
            'modified'
        )


class ListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    items = ListOrderSerializer(many=True, required=False, source='list_order_set')

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = (
            'title',
            'id',
            'items',
            'created', 
            'modified'
        )
```

However, I am new to Django and Django REST and know not where to go from here. How can I both save and retrieve these generic, ordered, nested lists, keeping the intermediary ListOrder invisible?